# Them or their after despite?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, grammatical-case

What's the correct usage: embattled customers whose flats are in limbo despite **them** or **their** having made the payment? What's the logic?

Answer (score 1):

They can both be used to mean the same thing, especially in British English. This has been the case for over 300 years. Some people think that the possessive (e.g. 'their') form is more formal or old-fashioned.

[Possessive with gerund](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2637)

Comment: And some people think that the objective 'them' sounds unrefined!